# Wordpress update monitoring

Tags: linux, wordpress

Is there a way to monitor schema/update changes during wordpress 3.1 upgrade?

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

i have decided to modify wordpress upgrade.php file so it records database schema before and after an update.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your original database to another name and then update to 3.1.

Use a graphical mysql tool like mysql workbench.  Load in the new database, and then attempt to synchronize with the original database.  Before execution, mysql workbench will show you where the schema differs.  Note the changes and cancel the synchronization.

Comment: thanks for your input however i decided to modify upgrade.php script to record database schema before and after wordpress update. the difference between the two is the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to monitor it, but you can check the [database section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) on wordpress codex :)